# How can I check to see if binding is complete for a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a noob to coding so please be patient with me (I've not written anything in over a decade and it is not like riding a bike).

I am using wpf to create a client application and I need to be able to figure out when a combobox has been bound.

I tried using Items.count > 1 in an async call with a wait but the problem is some selection may not return any values.

Here is my code behind (It is an action based on the selection change of another combobox)

```
    private async void belistbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        beOslist.Items.Clear();
        belistbox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        while (hiddenPortallist.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            waitAction();
            await Task.Delay(4);             
        }

        var beval = belistbox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        enumImages(beval);

        while (hiddenbeOSlist.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            waitAction();
            await Task.Delay(4);
        }

        OSLabel2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        addCombobox();


    }
```

Comment: You can try subscribing to the [SourceUpdated EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you describe the context? Why you need this? You can try to use DataContextChagnedEvent or forcibly update bindings but I suppose that this is not the real problem.

Comment: @ Matias Will try the sourceupdated trigger.

@macieqqq:
In a nutshell:
1. User selects an option
2. in the background a generic list is populated on load, and a second list, that is linked to the user's selection is appended to the combobox
3. The delay present a "loading" label and checks to see if the new values from the user selection is populated.
4. The "loading" label is removed and the updated combobox is displayed.

Comment: Try using `SourceUpdated` / `TargetUpdated` events.

Comment: I decided to prepopulate an empty row to eliminate any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is completed when event Loaded triggers.
You can attach to the Loaded event. It works if the binding is not Async.